# Getline to read data from txt file

Tags: c++, getline, istream

I'm having a bit of a problem with extracting data from a simple .txt file with the getline command.

The txt file is very simple: a column of 400 numbers. I use a vector to store them with the following code:

```
int i = 0;
string line;
vector <double> vec;

while (getline(input, line))
{
    vec.push_back(i);
    N++;
    input >> vec[i];
    i++;
}
```

It correctly creates a vector of 400 elements but first line of txt file is ignored (I end up with vec[0] = 2nd line of txt file instead of 1st) and 399th element is 399 instead of the 400th line of txt file.

I tried several other ways to extract this data but it was unsuccessful.

Thank you for your help!

**EDIT:**

I have edited the code according to some of the remarks:

```
vector <double> vec;
string line;
double num;

while (getline(input, line))
{
    input >> num;
    vec.push_back(num);
}
```

Unfortunately, it still skips the first line of my text file.

**EDIT 2 --> SOLUTION:**

Thanks to all of your remarks, I realized that I was doing something wrong when using both getline and input >> num;

Here is how the problem was solved:

```
double num;
vector <double> vec;

while (input >> num)
{
    vec.push_back(num);
}
```

Comment: probable related/dupe but we need a [mcve] t confirm: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567291/why-does-stdgetline-skip-input-after-a-formatted-extraction

Comment: `i` is undefined. Any reason why you don't `push_back` just the content of `line`?

Comment: i is defined before the while (int i = 0).

As for the push_back, it doesn't completely solve my issue since I still lose the first line of my data file.

Comment: `while (input >> i) vec.push_back(i);`

Comment: I have updated the code with the variables declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You loose the first line due to reading from the file once more - here:

```
while (getline(input, line))
    // ^^^^^^^ Here you read the first line
{
    input >> num;
 // ^^^^^^^^ Here you will read the second line
```

You told you want a vector of doubles - like:

```
std::vector<double> vec;
```

So you should use `std::stod` to convert the line read by `getline` into a double. Like:

```
while (std::getline(input, line))
{
    // Convert the text line (i.e. string) to a floating point number (i.e. double)
    double tmp;
    try
    {
        tmp = stod(line);
    }
    catch(std::invalid_argument)
    {
        // Illegal input
        break;
    }
    catch(std::out_of_range)
    {
        // Illegal input
        break;
    }

    vec.push_back(tmp);
}
```

**Don't** do `input >> num;` inside the loop.

If you really want to use `input >> num;` then you shall **not** use `getline`. That is - you can use either but **not** both.

Comment: Actually, it's a vector of double.

Comment: I edited the original post with a code that makes more sense so I don't need to convert. It's still skipping the first line :(

Comment: @Einsiedler: Sorry but the new code doesn't make "more sense". **Don't** do `input >> num;` you have **already** read the first line of the file with `getline`. So you loose the first line. Try what I have proposed.

Comment: @Einsiedler I added some extra explanation of the problem with your approach. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for your remarks. I understand more clearly but unfortunately, stod is not defined (despite including all libraries) so it does not work here.

Comment: @Einsiedler `stod` is from C++11 - use `#include <string>`. Are you compiling for pre C++11? If you use gcc compiler add `-std=c++11` or `-std=c++0x`

Comment: Actually, thanks to your remarks regarding the fact that we shouldn't use both inside the loop, I found the solution (see edit). Thank you very much for your greatly appreciated help :)

Comment: @Einsiedler - Glad to help :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can read the entire file into a vector just by passing `std::istream_iterator` to `std::vector` constructor, without loops:

```
std::vector<int> v{
    std::istream_iterator<int>{input}, 
    std::istream_iterator<int>{}
};
```

E.g.:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <exception>

template<class T>
std::vector<T> parse_words_into_vector(std::istream& s) {
    std::vector<T> result{
        std::istream_iterator<T>{s},
        std::istream_iterator<T>{}
    };
    if(!s.eof())
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to parse the entire file.");
    return result;
}

int main() {
    auto v = parse_words_into_vector<int>(std::cin);
    std::cout << v.size() << '\n';
}
```

Comment: wow - that's cool. Will it throw the same exception as `stod`?

Comment: @Einsiedler What is your difficulty?

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin BTW: OP has changed the vector to double. Just in case you want to update your answer

Answer (score 0):

Change your while loop like below:-

```
while (getline(input, line))
{
    vec.push_back(line);
    //N++;
    //input >> vec[i];
    //i++;
}
```

Also try with below option

```
 do{
    vec.push_back(i);
    //N++;
    //i++;
 }while (input >> vec[i++]);
```

Comment: A push_back with a string? That's strange... It actually gives me an error:

Error: Can't call vector<double,allocator<double> >::push_back(line) in current scope

Comment: you should declare your vector like vector<string>

Comment: Doing so still gives me the same problem except that this time, the 399th element is empty. I still miss the first line of the txt file.

Comment: Just print line before adding it to vector and check. Probably you read the first line somewhere in your code. Add few more lines before your while loop

Comment: I have added a do while loop option in my answer. Try with that

Comment: Didn't succeed but I was shown the mistake in my code and now it's solved :) thank you for your remarks!

Answer (score 0):

You are starting by putting 0 in vector in first iteration:

```
vec.push_back(i);
```

then after you read first line you read next string, but stream get pointer  from file is already in different place, so you override this 0 and skip first value from stream. What is worse that is oddly converted to double:

```
input >> vec[i];
```

This way you will get wrong.
Try this:

```
while (std::getline(file, line)) {
    //In c++11
    vec.emplace_back(std::stod(line));
    //In c++ 98, #include <stdlib.h> needed
    //vec.push_back(atof(line.c_str())); 
}
```

This assumes you will always have proper file.

Comment: Thanks for your remark, I have edited my post. Can you tell me if that actually changes anything to your remark?